# click on img using jquery not working on mobile

Tags: jquery

i have following code

```
$('.radio-color').click(function () {
                            $('.radio-color').removeClass('selected');
                            $(this).addClass('selected');
                            var color = $(this).attr('value');
                            //alert('<input type="hidden" name="color" value="'+color+'">');
                            $('#product_color').val(color);
                            $('#h4_color').text('\u00A0' + color);
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            $('.flex-control-thumbs ').find("li:eq("+id+")").find('img').click();
                        });
```

everything is working fine on PC but the last statement is not working on mobile. which is:

```
$('.flex-control-thumbs ').find("li:eq("+id+")").find('img').click();
```

i have tried using touchstart, touchend etc options but none have worked for me so far. i am stuck on it for 3 days now. need immediate help.

thanks in advance

Comment: do you have a li with that id?

Comment: yes. everything is working fine. but for some reason only the last line wont work . and this functionality is working fine on PC as i have mentioned. so i dont think there is anything wrong in the code. and there are no errors in console too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?

```
var img = $('.flex-control-thumbs ').find("li:eq("+id+")").find('img');
$(img).trigger("click");
```

Comment: thanks voque but i have tried that too. it dosen't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Is it IOS you're having trouble with? I've been having trouble registering clicks in IOS myself. Apparently they don't allow that. There's a stack overflow answer somewhere that links to an IBM article explaining that.

One thing you can try doing is remove the ".click()" with something like ".remove()", just to make sure the element is being targeted correctly (maybe some mobile media query is shifting things around?)

Worst case scenario, can you replicate your click function without actually clicking the element?

Another thing you can try: Somewhere in your code, there must be a click function assigned to that element, right? Something like:

```
$('.the-element').on('click', function(){});
```

Try replacing that with

```
$('.the-element').on('click newTrigger', function(){});
```

Then in your code above, replace

```
$('.flex-control-thumbs ').find("li:eq("+id+")").find('img').click();
```

With

```
$('.flex-control-thumbs ').find("li:eq("+id+")").find('img').trigger('newTrigger');
```

I also see adding `cursor: pointer;` in CSS works for some people on the element to be clicked.

Comment: i am using samsung note 3 

the img im trying to click via jquery can be clicked when i touch it on mobile screen. but i want to click that img using jquery too.

i have cursor : pointer added to it already.

Comment: Understood, but I think some mobile devices prevent that sort of functionality, so you might have to just replicate the function that the click event would do, without actually clicking.

Comment: but i want this to occur when the user clicks the button. not otherwise.